# How do you explain ethernet cable problems to non networking people?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, cat5

We've recently been doing a large network migration in our datacenter.

We've had a few cables in this start to deliver really bad pings (in excess of 500ms on a LAN) before they could be replaced.  The cables we were replacing weren't made the best.  They where all hand made and the runs were so short on some of them that the bend radius was definitely too tight.  Some of them ran in bundles right in front of the heat exhaust of the power supplies.

The cables were running ok until we started pulling the ones surrounding them out.  Then a few started having the problem I mentioned above degrading performance and causing reliability issues.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to explain this to non networking people.  Is there any documentation that people could recommend or other methods?

Comment: This is not a constructive question for a Q&A site, but I'll give you one pointer: Tell them that it's similar to a bad fuel line from the gas tank to the engine.. if it has holes in it the car is going to suffer, and eventually stop.

Comment: I've searched quiet a while for this and while the question may not be phrased in such a way that you agree with the constructive nature of it it's a question that's not really answered out there as far as I can tell.  I'd love it if someone was just able to link me to a few people talking abut it or a manual about the expected lifespan of cables in a datacenter.

Answer (score 1):

"all cables were flaky. as soon as we touched the bird's nest, everything started to fail"  doesn't sound too technical, and it's accurate enough

Comment: ... but don't use phrases such as "a few cables in this start to deliver really bad pings" because even a senior manager should know that cables don't respond to pings.